# Error: mail.setToAddresses unexpected token ')'

Tags: email, class

I'm following a Batch Apex Class workbook example.
In the section that sends an email to the job's submitter, I'm unable to set any values for email variables.

At this line:
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

I get the error:
mail.setToAddresses unexpected token ')'

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Kevin

```
// Send an email to the Apex job's submitter
// notifying of job completion.
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setSubject('Account Stats Status: ' + a.status);
mail.setPlainTextBody
('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
' batches with ' + a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Singleemailmessage[] {mail});
```

========================================================================================
This is the entire class
I don't have a log file, I'm in the Eclipse editor.  The error is the red 'X' next to the line of code; - Save error: unexpected token ')'.
Since this is a workbook example I'll be editing the class once I can get it going to see how it works.

```
global class dardenAccountStats implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global final String query;

    global dardenAccountStats (String q) {
        query = q;
    }

    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(
                    Database.BatchableContext BC, 
                    List<sObject> scope) {
        delete scope;
        Database.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        AsyncApexJob a = 
            [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, 
            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email 
            FROM AsyncApexJob 
            WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()];
    }

        // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter
        // notifying of job completion.
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Account Stats Status: ' + a.status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody
        ('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
        ' batches with ' + a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Singleemailmessage[] {mail});
}
```

Comment: Could you share the full class code, and the actual error message from the debug log?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I just realized that the email code was not within the 'global void finish' method.  When I put it in the finish method it saved without error.

Learn something new each day.

Thanks